# How to calculate thrust ratios for an object with a non centered mass

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rocket-science

I am trying to figure out a formula that, given an initial thrust value, will give me the thrust value that I need to apply to each thruster (red) to make the overall thrust be straight up with no rotation. The kicker is that the center of mass (green) is offset and variable.

Example:[image]

What I have so far (most likely far off):

DistanceToCOM = Mathf.Abs(centerOfMass - Thruster.localPosition); ThrustRatio = DistanceToCOM / DistanceBetweenThrusters * 2; ; Thrust = Force / ThrustRatio; apply force to thruster, repeat for next thruster

PS: If it makes a difference, this is the first step for solving a 3d version of this problem with 16 or more thrusters.

Comment: Make the vector sum of all forces act at the center of mass. This will give you no rotation

Answer (score 1):

The vector sum of the *torque* of each thruster about the centre of mass must vanish.

The total angular acceleration of the object is proportional (modulo a possibly nontrivial moment of inertia) to the total torque around the centre of mass,
$$\mathbf{\tau}=\sum_i\mathbf{r}_i\times\mathbf{F}_i.$$
If this vanishes, the angular acceleration vanishes, and your craft's attitude will be constant.

Note also that this can be simplified in the 2D case by equating the force times the distance between the COM and the line of action of each thruster. However, working with the vector notation from the start will enable you to deal most easily with the 3D case.